# mongoose $push, $each, results in duplicates

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

**Syntax:**

```
{
  $push: { keywords: { $each: req.body.keywords }}
},
```

**Data:**

```
req.body.keywords
```

*contents:*

```
"keywords": ["windows","cybersecurity","passwords","chrome","security"]
```

**Action:**

```
findOneAndUpdate({}).clone();
```

Without the `clone()` at the end, just errors happen.

**PROBLEM: Duplicate keywords.**